# Export list<float> into excel file

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, ms-office

I have a List contains all float values( lets say  List<*float*> avgDifClosedLoop; )

Now to do more process I want to export them in excel.
how can I do this through c#?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did you mean to ask something more meaningful than that?

Comment: he asked HOW not where it is possible

Comment: @Артём Царионов - That's not what I saw. Regardless, [Stack Overflow is not a personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505) - we expect to see what was tried and the effort done by the asker before we answer.

Comment: What have you tried?  Also what do you mean by an excel file?  Is a delimited file or xml file acceptable?  If it has to be an MS excel formatted file what versions of Office have to support it.  Is Excel available on the machine that is exporting the list?

Comment: I meant *.xls, yes the microsoft office 2007 (included Excel ) is available on machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need an external library to do this (or [interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) classes that will require Office installed). But you can do this (without interop) using [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com).

example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;

namespace listFloatToExcel
{

    [...]

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //list of floats
            List<float> f = new List<float>();
            f.Add(4.323F);
            f.Add(34.54F);
            f.Add(12.4F);
            f.Add(454F);
            f.Add(0987.32F);

            // Create a new workbook and a sheet named "Floats"
            var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Floats");

            var rowIndex = 0;
            foreach (var n in f)
            {
                var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowIndex);
                row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(n);
                rowIndex++;
            }

            using (var fileData = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\listFloatToExcel\floats.xls", FileMode.Create))
            {
                workbook.Write(fileData);
            }

       }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: When I added the references I got the following errors for these two:    
using System.Windows.Documents;  
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;  

The type or namespace name 'NPOI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  
And same for namespace name 'Documents'

Comment: Did you actually add those things as references in the solution explorer? Not just the `using` at the top of your class?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this the very complicated way with COM Interop services and write directly to an instance of Excel. With this method you can call worksheet functions as though you were in Excel itself and coding in VBA (but better).

The quick and easy way to do this, and depending on what else you need to do and how many times you need to do it, is to write your list out as a CSV file a la

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
{
    List<float> f = new List<float>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in f)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(item.ToString());
    }
    string linetoWrite = String.Join(",", sb);
    sw.WriteLine(linetoWrite);
}
```

Then just open it in Excel and move on with your life

Answer (score 3):

As I see it you have two options:

1. Use [Excel Interop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel).

   This allows you to control exactly where and how the values get output, but it requires Excel to be installed on the system executing the code and more skill in coding.
2. Write the values to a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) File.

   Excel can read CSV files by default.  This method does not require anything more complex than writing a text file and does **not** require Excel to be installed on the generating system.  However you loose some control over how the files are output into the worksheet.

Comment: 3. You can use the system.io.packaging classes to directly write an xlsx file without excel. But it's still a pain (it's probably easier to start with a blank file as a template and edit it).

Answer (score 3):

The quickest, easiest way to get something into excel is to write it out as a CSV file.

If you need more than just the raw numbers (e.g. you want to format them too), then it's certainly possible to write xls or xlsx files directly using interop or system.io.packaging.